# SQL Server Insert Statement Hangs

Tags: sql, sql-server

Really hoping somebody can offer some advice here. I have a SQL Statement with the following structure:

```
SELECT <Columns> FROM (SELECT <More columns> FROM (SELECT <AllColumns> FROM View))
```

Some of the steps might seem unneeded but there is a reason for all of them

- The view contains data that is automatically updated each time our import processes run. It contains a rather large query that gathers data from several tables.
- From that view our clients can build their own queries in order to create SSAS databases for reporting purposes, hence the second query. Some additional logic like friendly names are also applied here.
- Sometimes our clients would like to inspect the data up close, and bringing back a 2GB query over a web application is rarely a good idea. So we have build a facility where the clients can select the data they would like to return from the main query, hence the outer query.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT (ColA, ColB, ColC) 
   FROM (SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF 
     FROM (Select * FROM FullView))
```

All of this works correctly but in one specific case there is a problem. In order to make the data retrieval as fast as possible we create a summary table in the database containing the results of the middle query. However, for one of our queries the summary table refuses to build. The queries can successfully create the table with the correct columns but the data will never get populated, the SQL Server statement simply hangs in the air.

I have tried the following:

- Originally the statement that creates the summary table was a SELECT INTO statement. It worked for all the queries except the one in question.
- Thinking that for some obscure reason resources might not get released I split the statement into a SELECT INTO statement with a WHERE clause of 1=2 (allowing the table to be created) and an INSERT INTO SELECT clause which will create the data. The SELECT INTO statement runs perfectly, the INSERT INTO SELECT clause does nothing.
- However, if I were to run the SELECT part of the INSERT INTO clause the query executes in under a minute, which is acceptable as that is how long the original view executes. But if I add the INSERT INTO statement at the front without changing any part of the SELECT statement the query hangs. Maybe it executes somewhere down the line but a query that returns less data going from a minute to several hours might irritate some people.
- I have looked at the sp_who2 results and there are no blocks in the system.

Does anybody have any advice or another place I can look for the error?

Thanks!

Comment: while running the query ,run sys.dm_exec_requests dmv in Parallel and see what is wait type

Comment: Wait_type = NULL. Last Wait_type = MISCELLANEOUS

Comment: Have you tried updating all statistics, and rebuilding all indexes?